# Efficient way to compute subgroup weighted proportions?

Tags: python, r, dplyr

Goal: compute several subgroup weighted proportions in a more efficient way (such as a function). Need to subset by two variables (var1, var2) in all combinations and calculate weighted proportion of outcome (var3). Working in R (but python solutions appreciated too).

Reprex:

```
# Reprex
library(dplyr)
library(weights)

df <- data.frame(
  var1 = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1),
  var2 = c(1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 2, 2),
  var3 = c("A", "B", "A", "A", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "A"),
  weight = rnorm(10)
)

# sub1 
sub <- filter(df, var1 == 1 & var2 == 3)
round(weights::wpct(sub$var3, weight = sub$weight), digits = 2)

# sub2
sub <- filter(df, var1 == 2)
round(weights::wpct(sub$var3, weight = sub$weight), digits = 2)

# sub3
sub <- filter(df, var2 == 2)
round(weights::wpct(sub$var3, weight = sub$weight), digits = 2)

# Looking for more efficient way to continue subgroups (with more vars and combinations)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is quite simple using `data.table`s `cube` function. This function can be used to compute a function over all groupings within multiple variables as well as overall groupings. However in `data.table` we have a slight problem, as it expects only a single value as output, and the function `wpct` gives a value for each group in `x` (`var3` in our case). Luckily the function names it's output, so encapsulating the result as `result = list(weights::wpct(var3, weights))` will allow us to transform it into a readable format.

```
set.seed(1)
library(data.table)
library(weights)

df <- data.frame(
  var1 = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 1),
  var2 = c(1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 2, 2),
  var3 = c("A", "B", "A", "A", "A", "B", "A", "B", "A", "A"),
  weight = rnorm(10)
)
setDT(df)
# Note that I use list(weights::wpct(var3, weight)), 
#  because I want to keep the result in *one* column.
res <- cube(df, 
            j = c(list(result = list(weights::wpct(var3, weight)))), 
            by = c('var1', 'var2'))
res
## Output
    var1 var2                  result
 1:    1    1                       1
 2:    1    2    1.3907765,-0.3907765
 3:    2    3      2.058925,-1.058925
 4:    1    3                       1
 5:    2    1                       1
 6:    2    2                       1
 7:    1   NA    1.2394648,-0.2394648
 8:    2   NA  1.03932354,-0.03932354
 9:   NA    1     -5.599793, 6.599793
10:   NA    2   -0.7351568, 1.7351568
11:   NA    3    1.7429624,-0.7429624
12:   NA   NA   0.92322427,0.07677573
```

The groupings are showed in "var1" and "var2", while this will also calculate for all overall groups (eg. `var1 = 1` and `var2 = *any*` and `var1, var2 = *any*`).
However as I noted above, this result is barely readable. We can however fix this simply by using `unnest_wider` from `tidyr` to explode the `result` column into a better format

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
res %>% unnest_wider(result)
# A tibble: 12 x 4
    var1  var2      A       B
   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>
 1     1     1  1     NA     
 2     1     2  1.39  -0.391 
 3     2     3  2.06  -1.06  
 4     1     3  1     NA     
 5     2     1 NA      1     
 6     2     2  1     NA     
 7     1    NA  1.24  -0.239 
 8     2    NA  1.04  -0.0393
 9    NA     1 -5.60   6.60  
10    NA     2 -0.735  1.74  
11    NA     3  1.74  -0.743 
12    NA    NA  0.923  0.0768
```

And now we have a readable format, where the first two columns indicate the grouping, and the remaining columns indicate result for each value of variable `var3`. Note that `NA` is returned if there is no value for `var3` within the specific grouping of `var1` + `var2`.

Answer (score 0):

You could have something like this:

```r
multi_filter <- function(data, ...)
{
  filter_vars <- rlang::enquos(...)
  all_vals <- lapply(filter_vars, function(x) {
    data %>% dplyr::summarize(vals = unique(!!x)) %>% dplyr::pull(vals)
    })
  val_df <- expand.grid(all_vals)
  only_first <- lapply(seq(nrow(val_df)), function(i) {
    filter(data, !!(filter_vars[[1]]) == val_df[i, 1])
  })
  only_second <- lapply(seq(nrow(val_df)), function(i) {
    filter(data, !!(filter_vars[[2]]) == val_df[i, 2])
  })
  both <- lapply(seq(nrow(val_df)), function(i) {
    filter(data, !!(filter_vars[[1]]) == val_df[i, 1] &
             !!(filter_vars[[2]]) == val_df[i, 2])
  })
  
  lapply(c(only_first, only_second, both), function(sub) {
    round(weights::wpct(sub$var3, weight = sub$weight), digits = 2)
  })
}
```

Which produces every combination, like this:

```r
multi_filter(df, var1, var2)
#> [[1]]
#>    A    B 
#> 0.47 0.53 
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>    A    B 
#> 0.35 0.65 
#> 
#> [[3]]
#>    A    B 
#> 0.47 0.53 
#> 
#> [[4]]
#>    A    B 
#> 0.35 0.65 
#> 
#> [[5]]
#>    A    B 
#> 0.47 0.53 
#> 
#> [[6]]
#>    A    B 
#> 0.35 0.65 
#> 
#> [[7]]
#>     A     B 
#>  1.16 -0.16 
#> 
#> [[8]]
#>     A     B 
#>  1.16 -0.16 
#> 
#> [[9]]
#>    A    B 
#> 0.38 0.62 
#> 
#> [[10]]
#>    A    B 
#> 0.38 0.62 
#> 
#> [[11]]
#>    A    B 
#> 0.73 0.27 
#> 
#> [[12]]
#>    A    B 
#> 0.73 0.27 
#> 
#> [[13]]
#> A 
#> 1 
#> 
#> [[14]]
#> B 
#> 1 
#> 
#> [[15]]
#>    A    B 
#> 0.39 0.61 
#> 
#> [[16]]
#> A 
#> 1 
#> 
#> [[17]]
#> A 
#> 1 
#> 
#> [[18]]
#>   A   B 
#> 0.4 0.6
```